# How can prevent OnTouch in ListView scroll

Tags: android, listview, ontouchlistener

I have situation where I have ViewPager containing 3 ListFragments. Each ListFragment containg ListView of course. I have custom layout for items. What I would like to achieve is that when I press&hold item new fragment starts with animation on top of current one. I would like to stop animation (remove fragment) as soon as user release item. I have implemented this as an onTouchListner (code below). The trouble is that while i am pressing item i am able to scroll ListView. I would like to prevent that.

```
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touchDownTime = event.getDownTime();
                    mDownX = event.getX();
                    mDownY = event.getY();
                    isOnClick = true;

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (isOnClick
                            && fragment
                                    .isAnimation()) {
                        if (!fragment.isReleased()) {
                            fragment
                                    .cancelAnimation();
                        } else {
                            fragment
                                    .startReleaseAnimation();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (isOnClick
                            && !fragment
                                    .isAnimation()
                            && (Math.abs(mDownX - event.getX()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD || Math
                                    .abs(mDownY - event.getY()) > SCROLL_THRESHOLD)) {
                        isOnClick = false;
                    } else if (event.getEventTime() - touchDownTime > 150
                            && !fragment
                                    .isAnimation()) {
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                        transaction
                                .add(R.id.container,
                                        fragment)
                                .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29)

This will prevent interception of touch events

try this

```
 @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    // Your code
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    // Your code
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```